# Nested RepeatingGrps within Java Design Issue

Tags: java, arrays, generics, nested

**EDIT:** I have two Objects I must map one to the other. The problem is that the attributes don't exactly match up. The object coming in I am mapping from is flat has a bunch of getters and setters. All very nice and easy to work with.
I have to map this to a an Object which has somewhat of a different structure, within Groups such as `SecAltIDGrp[]` and attritubes such as those below. Which is set using

```
ObjectToMapTo.setSecAltIDGrp(SecAltIDGrp[])
```

I have a few repeating groups which I must map with values from a getter from the flat object the problem is this. The object to be mapped to has Array[]s of Grps which must be populated by various different getters from the flat object. I cannot think of a clean way to do this.

For instance, I have a code an array of comments which has the following structure.

```
    public SecAltIDGrp[] populateComments(int NoComments)
    {

        SecAltIDGrp[] x = new SecAltIDGrp[NoComments];
        for(int i; i < NoComments; i++)
        {
            x[i].setAltID(obj.getVal);
            x[i].setAltIDSource(arg0, arg1);
        }
    }
```

however each element of the array the is populated by a different getter from the flat object...

I cannot thing a nice of doing this bar inserting a if statement within the array and passing in the object as a parameter. This is rather horrific coding.

I am supposed to do this for a number of such groups. With some of the array element setters requiring arrays themselves.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. I can't understand what you want to do, so it's very hard to help :(

Comment: Done an edit. Tell me if it is still unclear, I will go into as much detail as you desire

Comment: Can you explain/show this? "however each element of the array the is populated by a different getter from the flat object..."

Comment: such as `x[1].setAltID(obj.getVal)`
        `x[2].setAltID(obj.getVal1)`
        `x[3].setAltID(obj.getVal2)`

The getVal is a different method for each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Array, try using HashMaps, which will help you pass/store the objects more easily.
If you are not really interested with the hashmap keys, then you can simply use ArrayList.

The HashMap will store the require group, along with the key. The key here will be similar to the array Index, you were planning to use.

```
public HashMap< Integer , SecAltIDGrp > populateComments( int NoComments )
{
    HashMap< Integer , SecAltIDGrp > hmSec = new HashMap< Integer , SecAltIDGrp >();
    for(int i; i < NoComments; i++)
    {
          SecAltIDGrp x = new SecAltIDGrp();

          x.setAltID(obj.getVal);
          x.setAltIDSource(arg0, arg1);

          hmSec.put( i , x );
    }

    return hmSec;
}

public class SecAltIDGrp{
   String altId = "";
   String altIdSource = "";

   public void setAltIDSource(  String altIDSource )
   {
       this.altIdSource = altIDSource;
   }

   public void setAltID( String altId )
   {
        this.altId = altID;
   }
}
```

Make sure the getters and setters will also have the appropriate parameters to satisfy the generics to prevent any warnings during compilation.

```
public class ObjectToMapTo
{

   private HashMap< Integer , SecAltIDGrp > hmPrivGrp = new HashMap< Integer,SecAltIDGrp >();

   public void setSecAltIDGrp(  HashMap< Integer , SecAltIDGrp > hmSecAltIDGrp)
   {
          this.hmPrivGrp = hmSecAltIDGrp;
   }
}
```

this is how you set the particular group. store the hashmap instead of an array.
    ObjectToMapTo.setSecAltIDGrp( hmSec );

You will be able to iterate through the hashmap and be able to retrieve individual SecAltIDGrp

Some stuff to read up:
http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-hashmap-example.html

Comment: I do not have access to the either of the any of the Objects code. I can only embed them I will have to use a wrapper for them. or else map the Arraylist to an array. I'm pretty sure ArrayList has a method .toArray() I hope :)